# Tokening String for Format-Table

Tags: powershell, string-parsing

I'm attempting to do something that ought to be simple in Powershell, but I can't for the life of me figure it out.  I have a log file that looks like this:

```
item1:some text 1:more junk I don't care about.
item2:some text 2:more junk I don't care about.
item3:some text 3:more junk I don't care about.
...
```

I want to use Powershell to split on the ":", grab the first two items, and then somehow convert the result into something that I can pipe to Format-Table.  The end result would be output like this:

```
Column A           Column B
--------           --------
item1              some text 1
item2              some text 2
item3              some text 3
...
```

I am by no means, a Powershell expert, so please feel free to clean-up my code.  This is what I currently have (I've tried several variations):

```
Get-Content C:\Temp\test.log | %{
    $data = $_.split(":"); 
    $hashString = 'a = ' + $data[0] + " `n b = " + $data[1]; 
    ConvertFrom-StringData -StringData $hashString
} | ft @{Label="Column A"; Expression={$_.a}},  @{Label="Column B"; Expression={$_.b}} -auto
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use Import-Csv for that... :)

```
Import-Csv -Path your.log -Delimiter : -Header ColumnA, ColumnB
```

You can use any char as delimiter, including colon.

Comment: Your answer works for this case, so I marked it as accepted, but I'd still like a more generic answer to my question.  How does one objectize text so that it is in a format that can be displayed/manipulated with the format-table command?

Comment: Well, in such a case regex are usually answer. You just create custom objects from strings, and later can do anything you want: filter, sort, and - format as a table. I've blogged about using $Matches in a way that makes it very easy to achieve: http://becomelotr.wordpress.com/2013/01/07/quick-tip-matches-is-enough/ but there are many ways to skin this cat.